# spawning a daemon function and signal handler

Tags: c, daemon

I want to spawn a daemon and apply signal handlers and log them in a file. I'm not able to log signal handlers in file. Also I'm not sure if these signal handlers are working or not .... how to check them. please help

```
/* A signal handler */

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("Caught signal %d\t", signal);
    if (signal == SIGINT)
    printf("Interrupt (Ctrl-C)");
    else if (signal == SIGQUIT)
    {
    printf("QUIT");
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (signal == SIGABRT)
    {
    printf("Process Aborted");
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (signal == SIGTRAP)
    printf("Trace/breakpoint trap");
    else if (signal == SIGKILL)
    {
    printf("Kill");
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (signal == SIGTERM)
    printf("Termination");
    else if (signal == SIGCONT)
    printf("Continue if stopped");
    else if (signal == SIGTSTP)
    printf("Pause the execution");
    printf("\n");
}

Here is the main function

FILE *fp= NULL; 
fp = fopen ("Log.txt", "w+");
do
{
    daemon(1, 1);// fork to a background daemon process 
    //printf("daemon is not working");
    printf("daemon-ed \n ");
    /* Registering signal handlers */
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler); // Set signal_handler() as the
    signal(SIGABRT, signal_handler); // signal handler for these
    signal(SIGTRAP, signal_handler); // signals.
    signal(SIGKILL, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGCONT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);

    fprintf(fp, "%s", signal);
    fflush(fp);
    // Implement and call some function that does core work for this daemon.

    fclose(fp);
}while(-1);


 return 0;
```

Comment: Don't use printf in a signal handler. It is not signal safe. Period.

Comment: Probably the daemon() is connecting stdout to >/dev/null. Try to fprintf() to a file. It is not signal-safe etc. but at least you will see some logging if signal handler is working. To test them, use the kill command. Another thing: SIGKILL cannot be handled, so don't bother.

Comment: thats where Im having trouble, I don't know how to fprintf() to a file

Answer (score 0):

fprintf() to a file is really quite simple
The sample below is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

You need the file pointer you can declare that in main FILE * pFile for example

then give pFile value by using fopen

after that you can write to the file using fprintf

```
/* fprintf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   int n;
   char name [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
   for (n=0 ; n<3 ; n++)
   {
     puts ("please, enter a name: ");
     gets (name);
     fprintf (pFile, "Name %d [%-10.10s]\n",n,name);
   }
   fclose (pFile);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I use frpintf() here, I'm not taking any input .. I'm not able to apply here :(

Comment: This was just an example on how to print to the file. You could just have the program make the file and keep track of the location. In any case you could just do something like fprintf(TheLogFile, "Log this info"); It works somewhat like printf. You don't need to take input to use fprintf

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not required to put all the signal and daemon calls inside the loop. Registering signal is one-time process, so anytime you receive signals your respective signal handler will be called. Another thing, I am not sure why you didn't get a warning when you tried to do 'fprintf(fp, "%s", signal);'
You may use a global variable set it in the signal handler and use it to write the value in the log.

So your main should look like something like:

```
  int glb_sig; //Set its value in the signal handler
  main() {
  FILE *fp= NULL; 
  fp = fopen ("Log.txt", "w+");
  daemon(1, 0);// fork to a background daemon process
  printf("daemon-ed \n ");
  /* Registering signal handlers */
  signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  ...
  while(1) {

  }
```

Note: If you want to see your printfs then use daemon(1,1)